# How to change variables value based on git branch?

Tags: reactjs, git, branch

So Here are the keys available to me.keys value is same as my localhost and dev_phase1 branch and different for live branch,I am using react js a the frontend ,But if i use process.env.NODE_ENV then it is the same for dev_phase1 and live.I believe ,both live and dev_phase1 codes are checked out as build version (i.e. the env is changed to production ,but i want to distinguish between them)

```
let key="value1";//it should be same as local and dev_phase2
```

and

```
key="value2" //it should be for live
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'value2' : 'value1';

the NODE_ENV should be `production` in live build.
and `development` in local and dev.

If you want to run locally then you can run as `NODE_ENV=development node server.js`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!But what i needed was another environment for the development server ,so i Created another build with staging environment to it.so i now i have three environments ,i adjusted the values based on that .

1.development (local server)
2.staging(dev or basically testing server)
3.live server